# Create django question object with 4 not same choices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a question object in django without choices repeated.
Like:

```
1) 2
2) 5
3) 5
4) 7
```

2 and 3 have same value and should throw error or response(I'm using rest framework)

```
# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey('Field', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField(unique=True)
    choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ignored = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

any solution for this problem?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. The question as it is doesn't really relate to django or rest at all - why don't to implement what you can, and then ask specific questions about the behaviour you cannot get to work?

Comment: You should show your current data model, too.

Comment: for the db design your answer table that contain these value should be unique per related question

Comment: @SpoonMeiser i need to check choices by override .create() method in ModelViewSet, i tried by pass validated_data to create method but django shows this error : create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Request

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for you called [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) which does exactly what you want.

**For example:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  field3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  field4 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4',)
```

**And in your case:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
  field = models.ForeignKey('Field', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  question = models.TextField(unique=True)
  choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  choice4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  ignored = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'choice4',)
```

Comment: do you migrate your new changes?

Comment: can you send me a sample project to regenerate the problem?